# How can I left attachment filed null while sending mail in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, email

In C# I designed one application through which I can send emails from desktop...

I am also able to send email with attachment.....

But when I tried send mail without attachment it gives me error as **The Parameter FileName 
cannot be an empty string. Parameter name:filename**

so please tell how can I remove this error

```
private void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 25);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Timeout = 100000;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx@hotmail.com", "zzzz");
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress("xxxx@hotmail.com");
            msg.To.Add(textBox1.Text);
            msg.Subject = textBox2.Text;
            msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(textBox3.Text.ToString()));
            msg.Body = textBox4.Text;
            client.Send(msg);
            MessageBox.Show("Done");

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           textBox3.Text = dlg.FileName.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line:

```
msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(textBox3.Text.ToString()));
```

to:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text.ToString()))
    msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(textBox3.Text.ToString()));
```

It is the `new Attachment(textBox3.Text.ToString())` part giving you that error. When you don't type any path in that `textBox3` it is empty but in `Attachment` constructor it still tries to get file residing on that path, and when it fails to locate that file it gives you that exception. By simply not calling that `Attachment` constructor your problem will be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

check if the string is empty first

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text.ToString()))
{
 msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(textBox3.Text.ToString()));
}
```